# Is it possible to get document count with msearch API?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the `/_msearch` API to execute multiple queries with a single request.

But it does not allow me to specify the URL, so it looks like I can't get the document with `/_count` API.

Is there any way to get document count with msearch API?

Comment: Do you need the total document count of your index **regardless** of the query you're sending or the count of matching documents only?

Comment: @Val Yes, just need a total count. Each query in the msearch is unrelated to each other.

Comment: But a total count of what? Of the index being searched?

Comment: @Val The index specified by me, in the msearch API the first line is the target index, the second line is the query

Comment: Why don't you simply add another `match_all` query with `track_total_hits: true` and that will give you the total document count.

Comment: @Val I figured out, track_total_hits helped, I added to a random query and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another `match_all` query to your `_msearch` call, like this:

```
POST _msearch
{ "index": "index1" }
{ "query1" }
{ "index": "index2" }
{ "query2" }
{ "index": "index3" }
{ "track_total_hits": true, "size": 0, "query": {"match_all":{}} }
```